# `sleep(_:)` vs `asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, ios-multithreading

I have a value type for which a relatively long calculation is require to produce it (> 1s). I wrap this value type in an enumeration that expresses whether it is currently being calculated or is available:

```
enum Calculatable<T> {
    case calculated(T), calculating
}
```

The problem is this value is persisted. This means after the long running calculation, when I have the updated value, I try to persist it first before changing the property visible to the business logic. If persistence succeeds, the property is updated, if it fails, I want to wait and then try to persist again; with a catch — if any other values have changed that the calculated one depends on, we throw away the previously calculated value — stop trying to persist it — and submit a new `Calculation` operation to the queue — starting all over again. My initial attempt at that looked something like this:

```
/// Wraps a value that takes a long time to be calculated.
public class CalculatedValueWrapper<T> {

    /// The last submitted `Calculation` to the queue.
    private weak var latestCalculation: Optional<Operation>

    /// The long running calculation that produces the up to date, wrapped value.
    private let longCalculation: (_ cancelIf: () -> Bool) -> T

    /// Calculation queue.
    private let queue: OperationQueue

    /// The calculated value.
    private var wrappedValue: Calculatable<T>

    /// Update the wrapped value.
    public func update() {

        // Don't set if already being calculated.
        if case .calculated(_)=self.wrappedValue { self.wrappedValue = .calculating }

        // Initiate new calculation.
        self.latestCalculation?.cancel()
        self.latestCalculation={
            let calc: Calculation = .init(self, self.longCalculation)
            self.queue.addOperation(calc)
            return calc
        }()
    }
}

/// Executes a long running calculation and persists the result once complete.
class Calculation<T>: Operation {

    /// The calculation.
    private let calculation: (_ cancelIf: () -> Bool) -> T

    /// The owner of the wrapped value we're calculating.
    private weak var owner: Optional<CalculatedValueWrapper<T>>
    
    func main() {
        let result=self.calculation(cancelIf: { [unowned self] in self.isCancelled })

        let persist: () -> Bool={

            // In case the persistence fails.
            var didPersist=false

            // Persist the result on the main thread.
            DispatchQueue.main.sync { [unowned self] in

                // The owner may have been deallocated between the time this dispatch item was submitted and the time it began executing.
                guard let owner=self.owner else { self.cancel(); return }

                // May have been cancelled.
                guard !self.isCancelled else { return }

                // Attempt to persist the calculated result.
                if let _=try? owner.persist(result)  { 
                    didPersist=true 
                }
            }

            // Done.
            return didPersist
        }

        // Persist the new result. If it fails, and we're not cancelled, keep trying until it succeeds.
        while !self.isCancelled && !self.persist() {
            usleep(500_000)
        }
    }
}
```

I would have stuck with this, but after further research I noticed a prevailing sentiment that it was bad practice to sleep the thread in `DispatchQueue` items and `Operations`. The alternative that seems to be considered better, in the case of `DispatchQueue` for example, was to initiate another `DispatchQueue` item using `asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`.

That solution appears more complicated in my case as being able to cancel a single operation that encapsulates everything that needs to be done makes cancelling easy. I can hold a reference to the last `Calculation` operation executed, and if another one is submitted on the main thread while one is in progress, I cancel the old one, add the new one, and with that I know the old value won't be persisted because it is done on the main thread after cancellation has already been performed; and a `Calculation` must not be cancelled in order for it to persist its result.

Is there something about `DispatchQueues` or `OperationQueues` that would make the alternative solution more straightforward to implement in this case? Or is sleeping here totally fine?

Answer (score 0):

Make a RetryPersist NSOperation. Just before adding it to the queue, set its isReady to false. Have it do a dispatchAfter weakly capturing itself to set its isReady to true. Now you can cancel any RetryPersist operations in the queue, if the count of them where not ready, not cancelled is not zero you know there’s one waiting to go etc.